# get substring from string in C

Tags: c, arrays, substring, token

I am trying to write a program in C, which will allow me to get a string I want between two other strings that will be defined. To be more specific, my example string is

```
 "blahblah<mailto:agent007@example.org>blahblahblah"
```

and I need to be able to extract the "agent007" substring to a new variable. I have tried the strtok() method, but the thing is I can't extract the tokens to a new variable or an array. I have tokenized the string and the statement that would suite me fine would be something like " *if token[i] == "mailto" && token[i+2] == "example" then mailAdd = token[i+1] "* (in a pseudo-code way :) )

my program so far

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="blahblah<mailto:agent007@example.org>blahblahblah";
  char * tch;
  tch = strtok (str,"<:@");
  while (tch != NULL)
  { 
    printf ("%s\n",tch);
    tch = strtok (NULL, "<:@");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Of course, any other suggestion beyond tokens will be greatly appreciated -

Comment: Tokens seem reasonable to me. I'm not clear on what problem you're having. Why can't you extract the tokens?

Comment: Hello Jonathan. I can't seem to find a way to export the token to a char var and later on use it in the program for other calculations. Did I make sense ? :)

Comment: if you want to reuse it, you need to copy the `tch` string somewhere: `tch` itself keeps changing. Note that `strtok` changes the original string. After your loop, (if I didn't mess the calculations up) `str+0` points to "blahblah"; `str+9` points to "mailto"; `str+16` points to "agent007"; and `str+25` points to "example.org>blahblahblah".

Comment: @pmg:Thanks for your reply. But here's a tricky one : How will I be able to still get the "agent007" token without knowing beforehand the lenght of the string? :)

Comment: You just need to save the pointer, @Sakis. I'll update my answer below.

Answer (score 2):

My first thought was to use `strstr` for "mailto:" and `strchr` for the '@'

```
// pseudo code
char *mailto = strstr(src, "mailto:"); // possibly convert src to lowercase
char *atsign = strchr(mailto, '@');
while (mailto < atsign) *dst++ = *mailto++;
```

Of course that is a very rough draft. It needs lots of refining (failure to find the "mailto:" string or '@' char, error-checking, special cases, tests, ...)

---

Saving the `strtok` pointer

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  char str[] ="blahblah<mailto:agent007@example.org>blahblahblah";
  char * tch;
  char * saved;                     /* pmg */
  tch = strtok (str,"<:@");
  while (tch != NULL)
  { 
    int savenext = 0;               /* pmg */
    if (!strcmp(tch, "mailto"))     /* pmg, UNTESTED CODE, need to check case? */
    {                               /* pmg */
      savenext = 1;                 /* pmg */
    }                               /* pmg */
    printf ("%s\n",tch);
    tch = strtok (NULL, "<:@");
    if (savenext == 1)              /* pmg, UNTESTED CODE */
    {                               /* pmg */
      saved = tch;                  /* pmg */
    }                               /* pmg */
  }
  printf ("saved: %s\n", saved);    /* pmg */
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, I see what you did there :) Tested and working like a charm. Thanks a zillion pmg :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `strstr` to search for 'mailto:' and then `strchr` to search for '@' and take the characters in between. I never use `strtok` but I don't see what's wrong with what you've done.

Here's an example where `email` should point to "agent007" in your case. Error handling is missing here. This is destructive, meaning that it modifies the input string, but so does `strtok`.

```
char *mailto = strstr( str, "mailto:" );
char *at = strchr( mailto, '@' );
char *email = mailto + strlen("mailto:");
*at = '\0';
```

Comment: That IS however the problem I'm facing. :) How can I take those characters ?